# Rendering from texture to offscreen texture (FBO)

Tags: opengl, textures, glsl, gpgpu, fbo

I am trying to write a GPGPU program, by just copying contents of a texture to an output texture attached to FBO. However, I see that the input texture data is not being loaded or binded properly. I cannot understand what is wrong.

Here is my code:

```
void render()
{

  int i;
  float * result, *in;

  //allocating and filling data in the input texture

  result = (float * ) malloc(4*32*32*sizeof(float));
  in = (float *) malloc(4*32*32*sizeof(float));
  for(i=0;i<32*32*4; i++)
  {
    in[i]=1.0f;
  }


makeBuffers(); //makes the vertex and element buffers
makeTexture(in);  //makes the input textures
makeShaders();    //makes the vertex n pixel shaders
makeProgram();   //makes the program

glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, res.vertexBuffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(res.position, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(GLfloat)*2, (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(res.position);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, res.elementBuffer);
res.texture= glGetUniformLocation(res.shaderProgram, "intexture");


 
/* bind texture */
makefbo();  // making the offscreen frame buffer object 

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, res.texture);
glUniform1i(res.texture, 0);


glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,4, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (void*)0);

//    glFlush();   // i think drawing would be enough now. 

glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT);   //reading back data from the framebuffer
glReadPixels(0, 0, 32, 32,GL_RGBA,GL_FLOAT,result);

printf(" float values \n");
for(i=0; i< 32*4 ; i++)
  printf(" %f   ", result[i]);
printf(" \n");
}
```

and here is my maketexture() function

```
 glGenTextures (1, &res.texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,res.texture);
// set texture parameters
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
// define texture with floating point format
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGBA32F,
             texSize,texSize,0,GL_RGBA,GL_FLOAT,0);

// transfer data to texture
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,0,0,texSize,texSize,
                GL_RGBA,GL_FLOAT,data);
```

And here is my framebuffer object preparation and output texture binding:

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &res.fbo);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, res.fbo);
glViewport(0, 0, 32, 32);

glGenTextures(1, &res.tex);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, res.fbo);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA32F, 
         32, 32, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, 0);
 glFramebufferTexture2DEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 
                      GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, 
                      GL_TEXTURE_2D, res.tex, 0);
```

The data does not seem to be read properly. I tried to attach the input texture to a framebuffer object, and tried to read back the texture data immediately, and the data gets displayed fine then. However, when I try to render to an offscreen texture, it does not give the correct output. It gives just a bunch of zeros at the end of pixel shader execution.

The pixel shader takes the input texture and copies the data into the output texture: `outColor = texture2D (intexture, texcoord);`

Does anyone see any problem with this?

Comment: Please don't say that you create the texture, fbo, vao, etc. each time you render a frame.

Comment: I am not rendering everytime, this is a one time operation. I just need the data to be processed once.

Answer (score 0):

Your code lacks a lot of context, but I have the impression that you bind everything exactly one time and then just leave it that way. That's not how it's meant to be used and will likely not work.

The essential gist is, that if a texture is used as a FBO render target it must not serve as a sampling source. So you have to either unbind textures / FBOs as needed, so that things don't tread on each other's toes, or you're loading shaders which simply make forbidden texture accesses. IMHO unbinding is the simpler option (however with OpenGL-4.4 a bindless texture extension was released, which may become core in 4.5).

Comment: yes, I am binding everything exactly once, because i just need a one time processing of the data. I wont be rendering again n again.

Comment: regarding unbinding : I am trying to copy input texture to output texture as is, doesnt that mean that both the input and output texture should be bound to the render target at the same time?

Comment: @saipallavi: No, it means exactly not doing that. Bind the output texture to the FBO as color attachment with `glFramebufferTexture`. The input texture must be selected as sampling source by binding it to a texturing unit with `glBindTexture`.